# onKeyUp event is not working in IE but works in firefox

Tags: javascript

I m trying to get what user type in text box with javascript so i used this

HTML:

JAVASCRIPT:
function textTrack(e)
{
    alert(e.keyCode);
}

this works fine in firefox but not in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MSIE use the global event-object:

```
alert(window.event.keyCode);
```

Comment: I used it but still getting error. Is following html code is right    <input id="userData" type="text" value="" onKeyUp="textTrack(event);"></input> because when I start typing (i.e. when event triggers) IE shows javascript error.

Comment: To elaborate: your function can be structured to use the appropriate event depending on the browser. function textTrack(e) {if (!e) e=window.event; ...

Comment: If you get more errors, it will be useful to show us textTrack() .